# Visual Studio Add-In Manager - cannot disable add-in at startup because greyed-out

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have ApexSQL tools running inside Visual Studio Shell 2010 but the auto-completion is crashing Visual Studio. I want to disable the add-in so it doesn't run on startup. But when I go to Add-In Manager the startup checkbox is greyed out.

How can I disable this add-in so it doesn't run at startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the add-in modifies files that are under [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).  Run Visual Studio as Administrator and the checkboxes will be available.

This worked for me in VS2012, hopefully it does in VS2010 as well.

Source: [Denis Basaric](http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=653)